# Do you add in the "for all the Jews in this town" clause to Eruv Tavshilin?

Tags: food, yom-tov, tzibur-community, motzi-yedei-chovato, eruv-tavshilin

In the Eruv Tavshilin we say when there's holiday followed by Sabbath, the proclamation is:

> This *eruv* ("merging") shall allow us to cook, bake, insulate, and kindle on the holiday in preparation for the Sabbath.

In many texts, there's then the phrase in parentheses:

> For us, and all the Jews in this town.

So who's supposed to say that phrase?  Just the rabbi?  (Which rabbi, if there's more than one in town?)  You, if you think everyone else in town will forget to make an eruv?

Answer (score 3):

From [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 527:14](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/1/527/2):

Generally, everyone makes an Eruv for themselves. The Gadol Sh'Be'ir (great rabbi of the city) is supposed to include the whole city. (This inclusion only works under certain conditions, a person should not rely on it instead of making his own)

Later on, the Ba'al HaTanya ruled in his Siddur that everyone who makes an Eruv (not just the great rabbi of the city) should include everyone in the city (by having someone else accept the Eruv on behalf of the rest of the residents in the city), so the Chabad custom is that everyone who makes an Eruv includes everyone else in the city.

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you have to be zoche the food to anyone you are doing an eruv for? If so, what's the point of everyone saying it, if they aren't mezakeh the food?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I'm not sure I understand your question. You do have to be zoche the food for everyone, but that doesn't mean that they all have to have it. One person is mezakeh everyone. See here: http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/1/527/17.htm . If you look in the Lubavitch siddur you will see that it is done with someone else, who is mezakeh it for everyone.

Comment: Menachem, you mean the custom is for everyone to be zoche to everyone else al yedei acher for every eruv tavshillin? I thought you meant that everyone just said the line.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I edited my answer to clarify. Hopefully I succeeded.

Comment: Why did the Baal Hatanya enact this?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I don't know, perhaps some of the commentaries discuss it. Perhaps there are opinions that everyone should do it and the Baal HaTanya chose to follow those opinions in the siddur (his later ruling)

Answer (score 2):

Here it seems to Indicate if you are Making an Erev For others then you say it

http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1424&ArticleID=5166&Page=1
Seems to agree
http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5759/shavuotnaso59/specialfeatures.htm