# Why does the eruv tavshilin only apply to Jews in this city?

Tags: geography, eruv-tavshilin

When we make an eruv tavshilin, we often close with "[for us and for all the Jews in this city.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/do-you-add-in-the-for-all-the-jews-in-this-town-clause-to-eruv-tavshilin)" so that others [who forgot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3117/if-you-forgot-to-make-an-eruv-tavshilin) or aren't observant can rely on your eruv for their own shabbas preparations.

But why do we limit the eruv to our city?  Why not country or world?  Is the idea that other Jews in our city can be expected to share the food we've prepared for shabbas (or use it in their own meals)?

Comment: btw The phrase "for all the Jews in this city" only applies if you include them through someone woh is not part of your hoiuseghold at the time you make the eiruv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud ([Beitza 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=16b&format=pdf)) writes:

> אבוה דשמואל מערב אכולה נהרדעא, רבי אמי ורבי אסי מערבו אכולהו טבריא. מכריז רבי יעקב בר אידי: מי שלא הניח ערובי תבשילין - יבא ויסמוך על שלי. ועד כמה? אמר רב נחומי בר זכריה משמיה דאביי: עד תחום שבת
>   the father of Samuel used to set the ‘erub for the whole of Nehardea; R. Ammi and R. Assi used to set the ‘erub for the whole of Tiberias. R. Jacob b. Idi proclaimed: He who has not set an ‘erub tabshilin, let him come and rely upon mine. And how far? — R. Nahumi b. Zecharaiah said in the name of Abaye: As far as the Sabbath limit. (Translation of [Soncino](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Beitzah.pdf))

The Mishna Berura (OC 527 sk 29) notes that the need is for the person to be able to come take from the Eruv food. This makes sense because setting aside food that is unreachable can hardly be considered beginning to prepare a Shabbat meal.